# running Hello World with Apache CXF & Apache ant?

Tags: web-services, ant, cxf

I know stackoverflow is a place for professional programmers but since my boss asked me to run a sample code of using cxf & sadly my computer knowledge is not good enough in this area I thought you guys can help me.few days ago I started to find a hello world sample on the internet. I was following the below tutorial: 
https://sites.google.com/site/ddmwsst/ws-security-impl/cxf-web-service-n-client
https://sites.google.com/site/ddmwsst/ws-security-impl/cxf-web-service-n-client

but i am stucked at this part :

"We are going to use ANT and write a build.xml. The build.xml is placed in HelloWorldService directory. Major target in the build.xml are
runWSDL2Java, compile, createWar

Run ant target runWsdl2Java and refresh src folder by pressing F5. You should see packages com.ddmwsst.helloworld and com.ddmwsst.helloworld.types are created"

what exactly should i do? would you please explain the above part **step by step**?

sorry for my bad english & thanks for saving my career :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANT is a build tool. It is using a build.xml file where some targets are defined (runWSDL2Java, compile, createWar). This file should be located in your project directory (HelloWorldService).

Under eclipse, right click on build.xml and run the target runWSDL2Java to generate the source files.